# I have three tables in a many to many relationship want to get results as raw data boolean

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

Say I have

```
users.id

roles.id

usersroles.users_id, usersroles.roles_id
```

How can I get the following headers for say user 1 with a triple join (I think IF clause in select?):

```
users.id, roles.id, (tinyint)has_the_role
1,1,0
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,4,0
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to only distinguish role 2 and 3? So any other role would be 0? BTW, your instinct in IF clause is accurate -- select if(roles.id=2,'1','0')

Comment: I want to select all of the roles in the table regardless of if the user has an entry in the many-to-many table for it.  If they don't have that entry, I want the boolean bit to be a 0.  If the entry exists, the bit is 1.  has_the_role is not a real column, but will be calculated by the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two joins for that:

```
SELECT users.id, roles.id, 
    CASE WHEN usersroles.roles_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_the_role
FROM users
INNER JOIN roles
LEFT JOIN usersroles ON users.id = usersroles.users_id AND roles.id = usersroles.roles_id
```

First you join the users table with the roles table (no condition, so all possibilities are joined) and after that you check if there is a usersroles entry for a specific combination.